# Simulate a network drive (with Loopback Adapter?)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, networking, windows-10

I want to simulate a network drive. It seems that the simplest way would be to use [Microsoft Loopback Adapter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/236869) but all of the instructions I've found on the web how to install it refer to non existing options in Windows 10. Is it not available in Windows 10 or how do I install it?

If it's not available - how can I simulate a network drive? Somehow make a folder recognized as a drive? Make an external HDD behave like that? Something else? (the router doesn't have a USB port so I can't use that.)

If there's some software emulation for testing applications that would be fine. I'm using C#. Perhaps something in Visual Studio?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to do in C# and what you are willing do to from command prompt?  Do you want to share a folder on your local machine and connect to it via SMB from inside your c# app? Do you want to do everything from c#?

Comment: @KoryGill I want to have the ability to test how my app works with a network drive without having one. How I set up that drive can be done any way.

Comment: Still confused. I think of network drive like z: is \\server\share.  server could be your own machine (127.0.0.1). If you want Loopback so you can have another IP on your machine to test client/server code, then you can add that via Device Manager add hardware wizard (although same machine, different ports, or named pipes can work too).  Unsure what to suggest here...

Comment: @KoryGill I found the answer. Posted below. (Now I just have to figure out how to use the adapter...)

Comment: @KoryGill Your idea of having another IP for my machine seems like the simplest way. How would I do that? If it's too complicated - maybe you can answer my followup question about [how to use the loopback adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048805/configure-loopback-adapter).

Comment: Based on what I have learned from this question: you should search `how to share a folder in windows 10` in your favorite search engine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101825/discussion-between-kory-gill-and-ispiro).

Answer (score 0):

It's been renamed to "Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter". ([MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2777200))