# Configure loopback adapter

Tags: c#, windows, networking

**Tl;dr** How do I access my computer's files using loopbacking?

I need to test my code with a network drive without having one installed. For that, I've installed the Microsoft Loopback Adapter. I can now access it under "Network connections".

Under its properties -> configure -> advanced I've set its network address to 192.168.0.123 .

But it doesn't seem to do anything. I can't, for example, enter that address in a browser or windows explorer and see my computer's files.

How can I achieve that? It doesn't have to be by explorer - if I can do it from C# that's fine because that's the goal anyway.

Comment: Are you sure you're understanding the term "loopback adapter"? What do you think it does, what do you expect to happen? You can just share a directory and access it by using your machine's hostname, or `localhost`, or one of its assigned IPs, or through 127.0.0.1 or ::1, no need for a loopback adapter there.

Comment: @CodeCaster `Are you sure you're understanding the term "loopback adapter"?` - Nope. I want to be able to browse my files with `\\server\folder1\` and I definitely don't know how to do that. I thought that's what this adapter is for.

Comment: If you've set up SMB and shared a directory, you can just access that share on your own machine through `\\localhost\SharedDirectoryName`.

Comment: @CodeCaster `SMB`? Sorry, I don't know what's that. I didn't "set up" anything except for the loopback adapter.

Comment: I already mentioned this in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045714/simulate-a-network-drive-with-loopback-adapter. This question does not seem valuable based on what you are trying to do, and my not be approprriate for SO (non-programming).

Comment: SMB is Server Message Block, Windows' default file sharing protocol. If you haven't set up file sharing and didn't create a share, accessing your machine through UNC (`\\machinename`, or `\\127.0.0.1`, or `\\ipaddress`) isn't going to do anything.

Comment: Search `how to share a folder in windows 10` in your favorite search engine.

Comment: @KoryGill `What topics can I ask about here? ... software tools commonly used by programmers;` (From [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Apparently it's so common that no one needs any help with it. Except me, that is :)

Comment: No worries on my side...I am trying to point you where you need to go to learn about such things.

Comment: @KoryGill Thanks. But I do know how to share a file - it's quite simple through file explorer. The problem is to access it as if it's on a separate computer (UNC ?)

Comment: @CodeCaster a) Thanks for the help. b) I didn't have to setup SMB, It seems that sharing the folder was enough and I can now access it with a UNC path. (I'm not even sure that the sharing was needed.) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. It seems it's trivial (once you know what to do...).

Just use the UNC path. No setup required. (I did share the folder through explorer's UI. But it I'm not sure that was needed.)